# Got a limit exception error even when the soql query is outside the for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, recursion, limitexception

just a question. Let's say I have apex class that are updating bunch of records using dml in a list which will trigger if the picklist is change, then execute the code. If a dml is triggered, will this be in same transaction? I'm asking because I have soql query inside the method but outside the for loop, yet it's still causing an error of limit exception...

Example..

```
public class RunApex {
    public static void metA(List<CustomObj__c> newRec, Map<Id, CustomObj__c> oldRec)) {
        List<History> histories = [Select Id From History]; // error is pointing in this line
            
        for(CustomObj eachOne : newRec) {
            if(eachOne.pckList__c != oldRect.get(eachOne.Id).pckLisy__c) {
                // execute code that assign the records to update
            }          
        }
        // dml update to List
    }
```

I have this code declared in the update before trigger but as you can see it's still causing limit exception even though the soql query is outside the for loop.

Comment: DML inside of a loop is just as bad as having a query inside of a loop. Also, if you're doing DML on the same records as you're getting through your trigger, you shouldn't be (the entire purpose of before triggers is to make adjustments to triggered records so you can avoid DML.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: The error is telling you where you went over a particular limit, _but that doesn't mean that location is the heart of the issue_. Limits are cumulative across the entire transaction (i.e. for everything that gets recorded in an individual execution log). You could have one class using 100 queries, and then this one would fail when you try to execute one more. You're going to need to dig through your execution logs to get a better picture of what's happening and where you're using queries.

Comment: Also, yes, any DML that you perform in a given transaction is still part of a single transaction. Only things like going async (or chaining an async call), publishing a platform event (if you have a trigger/flow for that platform event), or having a user click "save" in the web UI get you into a different transaction.

Comment: how many history records are in org? If you can tell what error you are getting that will also give us idea.

Comment: Hi, sorry it was a typo. But my dml is outside loop when I encounter the limit exception..

Comment: Be specific about the exact Limits error; use [edit], not comments